# When submitting form it takes me to the right page, but gives a 404 error

Tags: html, forms, http-status-code-404

I have a very simple form:

```
    <form name="password_test" action="landingpage.html" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="user" id="user"><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

When I submit the form it takes me to the correct page while giving me a 404 error. I can cut and paste the URL on the 404 page into the same browser window and it will take me to the right page with no 404 error. If I change the action to

`action=""`

then it will refresh to the same page without creating a 404.

In addition, if I change the method="post" to method="get" it will also work correctly, but obviously not as I would like it to. This is on my localhost set up through a Sprint Tool Suite (I'm not sure if that's relevent at all). Has anyone else ever seen this before? At work it only deploys to the dev region every 12 hours so I am hoping to correct the issue before it elevates.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You action is redirecting to HTML page you should redirect to PHP file

Comment: Do you have this page set up to only respond to get requests and not post?

Comment: Ko2r, could you explain why please? I should explain additionally, that I'm not doing anything with the login or checking against any data whatsoever. It's testing a traffic monitor system. And, unfortunately, PHP is not an option where I work...

Comment: Kritner, I didn't even realize you could set a page to not respond to post requests. I generally work in PHP for any web work but that option is not available to me here.

Comment: Why are you setting `action` to an html page..? What do you actually want to happen upon form submission...?

Comment: Tilwin, I should explain additionally, that I'm not doing anything with the login or checking against any data whatsoever. It's testing a traffic monitor system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was actually nothing wrong with the code. It doesn't matter that I was making a POST to an html page ( again, I was just trying to monitor web traffic ). As soon as my code was elevated it started working correctly. I assume it has something to do with the way my localhost is set up currently.